# Facebook Graph API Page Post Publish Shows 'Graph API Explorer' tag

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook Graph API to post to my page and it displays 'Graph API Explorer' tag as a source from which I sent a post, even though I use API endpoint.

Is there a way to customize this tag or remove it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, It was the Application I created token for. Simply changed the application when creating user access token and it displays it